# Heroku app deployed successfully, but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, zeitwerk

M receiving following error message while opening the app.........
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Here are the logs...What am i missing here???

```
2021-03-01T17:03:26.388992+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.389017+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.389040+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.389066+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.389089+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.389113+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2021-03-01T17:03:26.491419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-01T17:03:26.561190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-01T17:03:26.566083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-01T17:03:40.426026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2021-03-01T17:03:42.175927+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user vineet19.rawat@gmail.com
2021-03-01T17:03:50.395757+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2021-03-01T17:03:50.395777+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in production
2021-03-01T17:03:50.395778+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2021-03-01T17:03:52.776562+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2021-03-01T17:03:52.776980+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:17:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/controllers/example_user.rb to define constant ExampleUser, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777048+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:28:in `block in require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777075+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `tap'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777102+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777126+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:392:in `const_get'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777151+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:392:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777207+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:742:in `block in ls'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777234+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:734:in `foreach'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777259+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:734:in `ls'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777282+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:387:in `block in eager_load'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777303+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:376:in `synchronize'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777327+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:376:in `eager_load'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777387+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:494:in `each'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777410+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:494:in `eager_load_all'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777434+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:122:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777459+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777507+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777574+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777598+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777623+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777646+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777670+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777711+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777751+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777773+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777798+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777821+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777845+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777868+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777922+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777947+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777971+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.777997+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778021+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778059+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778100+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778125+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778152+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778176+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778198+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778244+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778282+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778308+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778354+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778400+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778440+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778465+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778513+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778576+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778615+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778640+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778686+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778710+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778752+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778789+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778813+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778838+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778862+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778886+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778925+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778964+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.778989+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.779014+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.779037+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.779060+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2021-03-01T17:03:52.858760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-01T17:03:52.957145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-01T17:03:54.875119+00:00 heroku[run.3338]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-01T17:03:54.983968+00:00 heroku[run.3338]: Awaiting client
2021-03-01T17:03:55.013747+00:00 heroku[run.3338]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2021-03-01T17:04:03.908104+00:00 heroku[run.3338]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-01T17:04:03.956135+00:00 heroku[run.3338]: State changed from up to complete
2021-03-01T17:04:17.990487+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed` by user vineet19.rawat@gmail.com
2021-03-01T17:04:31.107131+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-01T17:04:31.517826+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Awaiting client
2021-03-01T17:04:31.554963+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed`
2021-03-01T17:06:22.786614+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-01T17:06:22.861553+00:00 heroku[run.7311]: State changed from up to complete
2021-03-01T17:09:19.967120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=still-scrubland-60280.herokuapp.com request_id=d8dd773f-4e4d-4b93-9870-6dbc62b7de02 fwd="157.38.50.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-01T17:09:21.311235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-scrubland-60280.herokuapp.com request_id=843f886d-790e-4e08-ba71-0a14f728b3f9 fwd="157.38.50.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 3):

When this happens it usually means you have a bug in your code, and the rails app crashes when it hits this bug. The error can usually be found by reading these stack traces carefully. In your case this looks like the error: `2021-03-01T17:03:52.776980+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:17:in on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/controllers/example_user.rb to define constant ExampleUser, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)`

Comment: Ya, I forget what I did to fix it, but with Rails6 I got this error a bit. If I remember correctly, it had something to do with load path or the way Rails looks up classes changed in Rails 6